# Dynamic components are overlapping in Recycler view in android?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have recycler view, which contains questions and answer fields .The answer fields are created programmatically as per the answer type. If the answer is "description" type then I am providing a edittext and if "true/false" type then toggle and etc .But while scrolling down and up all the dynamically created answer fields are overlapping.

```
public class CheckSuiteFormAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

        private List<AuditToday> formList;
        Context context;
        FrameLayout frameLayout;
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams date_param;
        int mYear,mMonth,mDay;
        HashMap<String,String> hsAllAns;
        private boolean hasLoadButton = true;
        private final int TITLE = 0;
        private final int LOAD_MORE = 1;
        AuditToday auditToday;
        public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
            public TextView question_no, question ;
            public EditText answer;
            public Button btn_attach,btn_submit;
            public  CheckBox cb;
            public ToggleButton toggleButton;



            public MyViewHolder(View view) {
                super(view);
                context = view.getContext();
                question_no = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.id_qs_no);
                question = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.id_qs);
               // answer = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.id_ans_text);
                btn_attach = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_attachment);
                frameLayout = (FrameLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.id_frame_layout);


                //create view dynamically start ------------>

                FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                        FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                );
                params.setMargins(30,100,0,0);
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams params_toggle = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                        FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                );
                params_toggle.setMargins(60,100,0,0);
                date_param = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(50,30);

                answer = new EditText(context);
                answer.setLayoutParams(params);
                frameLayout.addView(answer);
                cb = new CheckBox(context);
                cb.setText("Dynamic Checkbox " );
                cb.setLayoutParams(params);
                frameLayout.addView(cb);

                toggleButton = new ToggleButton(context);
                toggleButton.setLayoutParams (params_toggle);

                frameLayout.addView(toggleButton);

                //visibility based on values
                answer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                cb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                toggleButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                //text_date.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                hsAllAns = new HashMap<>();
                //create view dynamically end ------------>
            }
        }
        public CheckSuiteFormAdapter(List<AuditToday> formList) {
            this.formList = formList;
        }

        @Override
        public RecyclerView.ViewHolder  onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            if(viewType == TITLE) {
                View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.form_list_row, parent, false);
                return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
            }else if (viewType == LOAD_MORE) {
                return new FooterViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.checksuite_form_submit, parent, false));
            } else {
                return null;
                }
        }


        class FooterViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            Button btn;

            public FooterViewHolder (View itemView) {
                super (itemView);
                this.btn = (Button) itemView.findViewById (R.id.btn_submit);
            }
        }




        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

            if(holder instanceof MyViewHolder) {
                MyViewHolder headerHolder = (MyViewHolder) holder;
                auditToday = formList.get(position);
                headerHolder.question_no.setText(auditToday.getQuestion_no());
                headerHolder.question.setText(auditToday.getQuestion());
                String ans_type = auditToday.getAnswer();
                if (ans_type.equals("desc")) {
                    headerHolder.answer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    String response_desc = headerHolder.answer.getText().toString();
                    Log.d("SUBMIT","response_desc :"+response_desc);
                  //  hsAllAns.put(auditToday.getQuestion_no(), response_desc);
                } else if (ans_type.equals("chk")) {
                    headerHolder.cb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    boolean responce_b = headerHolder.cb.isChecked();
                    String res_bol = String.valueOf(responce_b);
                    Log.d("SUBMIT","res_bol :"+res_bol);
                    //hsAllAns.put(auditToday.getQuestion_no(), res_bol);

                } else if (ans_type.equals("num")) {

                    headerHolder.answer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    headerHolder.answer.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);

                    String response_num = headerHolder.answer.getText().toString();
                    Log.d("SUBMIT","response_num :"+response_num);
                   // hsAllAns.put(auditToday.getQuestion_no(), response_num);

                } else if(ans_type.equals("toggle")){
                    headerHolder.toggleButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    boolean responce_b = headerHolder.toggleButton.isChecked();
                    String res_bol = String.valueOf(responce_b);
                    Log.d("SUBMIT","res_bol :"+res_bol);
                   // hsAllAns.put(auditToday.getQuestion_no(), res_bol);
                }

            } else if(holder instanceof FooterViewHolder) {
                FooterViewHolder footer = (FooterViewHolder) holder;
                footer.btn.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener () {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick (View view) {
                        Toast.makeText (context, "Clicked Header", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();
                        Gson gson = new Gson();
                        String json = gson.toJson(hsAllAns);
                       Log.d("SUBMIT","hs value :"+json);
                       // hsAllAns.clear();

                    }
                });
            }

        }


        public boolean isHasLoadButton() {
            return hasLoadButton;
        }

        public void setHasLoadButton(boolean hasLoadButton) {
            this.hasLoadButton = hasLoadButton;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
           // return formList.size();
            if (hasLoadButton) {
                return formList.size() +1;
            } else {
                return formList.size();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            Log.d("sss",position+"a"+getItemCount());
            if (position >= formList.size()) {
                return LOAD_MORE;
            } else {
                return TITLE;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are setting visibility for your answer fields in onBindViewHolder you should set visibility GONE for other fields.
For example, instead of:

```
headerHolder.answer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Do:

```
headerHolder.answer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
headerHolder.cb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
headerHolder.toggleButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

It may seem redundant (you are hiding the views in a constructor of MyViewHolder) but RyclerView will reuse your viewholder instances. When it's recycled for other type of answer, previously displayed view will remain visible.

Comment: Can you please say how can I retrieve values from all those edittext and checkboxes on button click?

Comment: You mean the button in the footer?

Comment: I any case, you need some kind of model for your rows and store user entered values there when user enters them. Once a row leaves the screen its view will be recycled and you will lose entered state. You can store it to AuditToday object in list or you can have separate list and class for answers.

Comment: Is there a better approach to create those edit text and check boxes so that the data retrieval from the fields will be easier ?because I am following visibility GONE and VISIBLE approach by which data retrieval is hard .